# Append to window.opener.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends,

Is it possible to append a string to the window.opener.location from the opened window? Ideally, the opener does not refresh, but gets "&t=test" added to then end of it.

Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score -1):

Nope, the only thing you can change in the url is the fragment, changing anything else will reload the page, e.g. you can change `http://www.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/#t=test` and then you need to use javascript to parse the value of `t` from the fragment.

Comment: could you please explain why?

Comment: Sure.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history.

Comment: well but that is not true across all browsers, the best way to do it if you is still via fragments, isn't it? Or are you saying this works in IE7/IE8?

Comment: @scibuff: nope, the best way to do it is use history manipulation if possible. If not, fall back to fragments.

Comment: Is history manipulation possible from within an iframe? In my case the iframe is the opener.

Comment: @AdamStorr: as long as you're not violating the same origin policy (ie, domains are the same for both pages), you should be fine.